# ActionScript File Upload very slow

Tags: performance, file, actionscript, upload, mxml

My requirement is to upload 5000 images to WAMP server from AIR client.
I am using URLRequest to upload the images.
The size of each image is about 285 KB.
Able to only upload about 300 images only. The server becomes unresponsive and the client stops uploading.
This is urgently required. 
Please let me know how do I finetune for performance/or go about solving this issue.

Thanks
Jad

Answer (score 0):

> `5000 * 285 KB = 1425 MB (or 1.4 GB)`

Do you see why the uploading is slow and the server becomes unresponsive?

Use a load-queue - put the image names in an array and load them one by one. Start uploading an image only from the `complete` event handler of the previous image.

And make sure that the server has enough space to begin with.